# Writing error handling and users routing for my JSON RESTful API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

I'm currently making an app for my side project and I was looking to get some insight on the main js file, what can I improve, the error handling, what am I doing wrong, etc. I'm mostly confused about the error handling.

This is the main javascript file:

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()

// Require routes
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')

// Configs
require('./cfg/mongoose')

// Express middlewares / settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// Environment specific middlewares
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.use(morgan('combined'))
} else {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// Routing
app.use('/users', usersRouter)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the API! '
  })
})

// Handles 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send({ error: 'Invalid endpoint' })
})

// Generic error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.errors) {
    let errors = {}
    for (const errorName in err.errors) {
      errors = { ...errors, [errorName]: err.errors[errorName].message }
    }
    res.status(400).send({ errors })
  } else {
    res.status(err.output.statusCode).send({
      message: err.message || 'Internal server error'
    })
  }
})

// Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${app.get('port')}`)
})
```

And this is the users route:

````js
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from '../models/User'
import boom from '@hapi/boom'
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { phone_number, email, password, name } = req.body
    try {
        const newUser = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            phone_number,
            password,
        })
        res.status(201)
            .set('Location', `${req.hostname}${req.baseUrl}/${newUser.id}`)
            .send(newUser.id)
    } catch (err) {
        next(boom.boomify(err, { statusCode: 400 }))
    }
})

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let users
    try {
        users = await User.find({}, 'name email').lean()
        Object.values(users).map(user => {
            user.profile_url = `${req.hostname}${req.baseUrl}/${user._id}`
        })
        if (!users.length) next(boom.notFound('Cannot find any users'))
        res.status(200).send(users)
    } catch (err) {
        next(boom.badImplementation())
    }
})

router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(
            req.params.id,
            'name email phone_number'
        )
        res.status(200).send(user)
    } catch (err) {
        next(boom.notFound('User not found'))
    }
})

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await User.deleteOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) })
        res.sendStatus(204)
    } catch (err) {
        next(boom.notFound('User not found'))
    }
})

router.put('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    let user
    try {
        const { email, phone_number, password, name } = req.body
        user = await User.findOneById(req.params.id, '-__v')
        user.email = email || user.email
        user.phone_number = phone_number || user.phone_number
        user.password = password || user.password
        user.name = name || user.name
        let updatedUser = await user.save()
        res.status(200).send(updatedUser)
    } catch (err) {
        next(boom.notFound('User not found'))
    }
})

module.exports = router
```
````

Comment: I wouldn't think that a database error should cause a status of 400 as the route was found just fine.  Probably should be 5xx for an internal server error.

Comment: I don't have much comment regarding the error handling, like @jfriend00 said the status of 400 makes more sense if it was 5xx. 

On another note: I havent used boom but I do like to create a global response object that I can always return in all my requests. I make sure it has a few properties like data, status and mabye error object. 

This way my front-end that consumes the API will always know exactly what to expect. I know that any data i request, will always be under the data property or any errors will be under my error property.